`define value assignment to a string
I am writing some SV code. I have 'define value which I want from terminal with +define for following `define ENV_TOP. the value should go in the config_db block as I am retrieving the value for running and initializing test instances. Check the code below.
What is correct way to do this ?
`ifndef ENV_TOP 
   `define ENV_TOP tb
 `endif

  env_base `ENV_TOP;   //env_base is class and I should get "tb" here as I am not defining ENV_TOP

  virtual function void build_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    string env_scope = `ENV_TOP;  //I should get here "tb" as well.
      if (!uvm_config_db#(env_cfg)::get(this,env_scope,"env_cfg", env_cfg)) begin
         ...
       end

    


Converting `define text to a string token requires another macro with an argument using the `" character.
`define STR(s) `"s`"

  string env_scope = `STR(`ENV_TOP);  //should get here "tb" as well.

See section 22.5.1 `define in the IEEE 1800-2023 SystemVerilog LRM
